# How to get the list of files modified for a particular svn log message?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am having some svn log messages which I found with a particular search criteria, using the following command 
`svn log "BranchURL" --search="CR123"`

The above command gives me log messages, but I also want the list of files modified in this particular log message.
Can anyone please help me in getting this list?

Answer (score 3):

Append [`-v` (`--verbose`)](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.verbose) to the command-line and you'll see the list of changed items.

SVNBook:

> --verbose (-v)
>
> Requests that the client print out as much information as it can while running any subcommand. This may result in Subversion printing
>   out additional fields, detailed information about every file, or
>   additional information regarding its actions.